# How to prevent Eclipse (Oxygen) from adding carriage returns to new lines?

Tags: eclipse

I recently upgraded Eclipse to v4.7 (Oxygen) on Ubuntu 16.04. Whenever I make changes to my Java files in my git repos, the diff show me that all the changes or new additions have a Windows-style carriage return at the end (which appears as `^M` in `vim`).

If I go into `Preferences -> General -> Workspaces` at the bottom I can see that the `Text file encoding` is set to `UTF-8` and the `New text file line delimiter` is set to `Unix`. I've also tried adding the system property `-Dline.separator=\n` to the eclipse.ini file.

How can I stop Eclipse from adding carriage returns at the end of new lines?

Comment: The workspace preference might be overridden by the project, by a folder or by the file properties (-> right-click and choose Properties: Ressource_).